# Turn off opaque resizing of QMainWindow / QDockWidget separator

Tags: qt, qt4

Is it possible to turn off opaque resizing on QMainWindow / QDockWidget separators?

(i.e. the central widget only resizes once the separator is dropped, and not during the drag.)

Answer (score 2):

QMainWindow has an [animated](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmainwindow.html#animated-prop) property that specifies whether animation is used for manipulation of dock widgets and tool bars.  By default, this property is enabled so you'll get dynamic (and animated) resizing of the central widget when moving dock widgets around.  Clearing it should give you functionality similar to turning off opaque resize in a QSplitter.

```
QMainWindow* mainWin(new QMainWindow);
mainWin->setAnimated(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could subclass `QSlider` and override `sliderChange(SliderChange change)` and not invoce the superclass method as long as the slider is still being dragged? That is assuming that this is the correct method that will eventually emit the signals that update the guy around. Haven't tested it, but thats generally a pattern that works in QT (for instance one can subclass the reject slot of QDialgo to abort dialogs).